# How to rewrite argmin in terms of the argument you are minimizing?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm reviewing some tutorial notes for a optimizing algorithm for a Quadratic equation, and this is confusing me. I get to the point where it says:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx $$

$$x^2 = argmin_{\lambda_1} f(x^1 + \lambda_1 s^1)  $$

which they equate to

$$ \lambda_1 = \frac{-\nabla f(x^1)^Ts^1}{(s^1)^TAs^1} $$

I'm confused how they solve for $ \lambda_1$ using the argmin.

I know $$ \nabla f(x) = Ax-b$$

but thats pretty much all I got.

Comment: The expression $x* = \text{argmin}_{x} f(x)$ means that $f(x^{*}) = \inf_{x} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are looking along a line, represented parametrically by $x = x^1 + \lambda s^1$ (where $x^1$ is the current solution and $s^1$ some direction), and they want $x^2$ to be the place on that line where $f$ is minimized.
Plugging $x = x^1 + \lambda s^1$ in to the definition of $f$, we get

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x^1 + \lambda s^1)^T A (x^1 + \lambda s^1) - b^T (x^1 + \lambda s^1)$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\lambda$, and set to $0$:
$$ 0 = \dfrac{1}{2} (s^1)^T A (x^1 + \lambda s^1) + \dfrac{1}{2} (x^1 + \lambda s^1)^T A s^1 - b^T s^1$$
Now solve this for $\lambda$:
$$ \lambda = \frac{b^T s^1 - (x^1)^T A s^1/2 - (s^1)^T A x^1/2}{(s^1)^T A s^1}$$

If $A$ is symmetric (which we may as well assume, because $A$ and $(A+A^T)/2$ give the same objective function) this simplifies to

$$ \lambda = \frac{b^T s^1 - (x^1)^T A s^1 }{(s^1)^T A s^1}
= \frac{(b - A x^1)^T s^1}{(s^1)^T A s^1}$$